# C# Gzip Write Custom Compress

Tags: c#, gzip, compression

i have this decompress method, and i want to make a compress one based on it. could anyone help me? (i tried myself write but didn't work)

Decompress Method:

```
public static byte[] Decompress(byte[] data)
{
   MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
   memoryStream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
   memoryStream.Position = 0L;
   GZipStream gZipStream = new GZipStream(memoryStream, CompressionMode.Decompress, true);
   MemoryStream memoryStream2 = new MemoryStream();
   byte[] array = new byte[64];

   for (int i = gZipStream.Read(array, 0, array.Length); i > 0; i = gZipStream.Read(array, 0, array.Length))
   {
        memoryStream2.Write(array, 0, i);
   }

   gZipStream.Close();
   return memoryStream2.ToArray();
}
```

THis is how i tried to write the Compress method, but didn't get the right result when i decompress it back:

```
public static byte[] Compress(byte[] data)
        {
            MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
            memoryStream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
            memoryStream.Position = 0L;
            GZipStream gZipStream = new GZipStream(memoryStream, CompressionMode.Compress, false);
            byte[] array = new byte[64];
            gZipStream.Write(array, 0, array.Length);
            gZipStream.Close();
            return memoryStream.ToArray();
        }
```

Comment: Do you have a _specific_ problem? Please read [ask].

Comment: i don't have other specification, i want to make the compress method based on the decompress one.

Comment: Then just try to do it. If you face some _specific_ problem - ask for the solution.

Comment: i edited my question, please check ti now.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the [ask] page for help clarifying this question.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use the following simple implementation:

```
public static byte[] Compress(byte[] data)
{
    using (MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
    using (GZipStream gzipStream = new GZipStream(memoryStream, CompressionMode.Compress, true))
    {
        gzipStream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
        return memoryStream.ToArray();
    }
}
```

Comment: yes, but in the decompress method, it read 64 bytes always, instead of all at once.

Comment: Is there a reason to read by short chunks if the method returns all the decompressed data as a single byte array?

Comment: yes there is. because later needs the result to be encrypted based on a another algorithm.

Comment: It's completely unclear what you are talking about. What is "result" exactly? Where is the encryption in the question? And still there is no *specific* question in the topic itself!

Comment: sorry for my bad english, i just want the compression method to work properly. if you could help me that would be great.

Comment: @Castiel both methods take in an array of bytes and spit out an array of bytes. The size of individual chunks read at a time while doing the compression/decompression is irrelevant.  Your `Decompress` method has a lot of extra unnecessary code.. better to rewrite it following Dmitry's `Compress` method.